# SQL Percentage Complete with COUNT and Remaining Percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Quite difficult to explain in the title so here is my scenario:

Let's say I have a value of £10,000, this is going to be paid in random instalments (up to 100%). The cumulative total is stored in a field called `PercentageComplete`.

> Payment 1 is £5,000 (PercentageComplete = 50% of total amount owed)
>
> Payment 2 is £2,500 (PercentageComplete = 75% of total amount owed)

So far the way I'm trying to work this out is by adding (0.5 + 0.75) which gives me a total of 1.25 ... and using the `COUNT` function I'm dividing this by 2 (which gives the incorrect answer of 0.625).

I'm probably over complicating this issue so thanks for any help.

The code I tried:

```
select FinanceID, CustomerID sum(PercentageComplete), COUNT(PercentageComplete) 
from Finances group by FinanceID, CustomerID
```

Comment: A simple question: Payment 2 is the 75% of the *remaining* total? It seems to be the 25% of the total (and 0.5+0.25=0.75).

Comment: First of all be clear 2500 is not the 75% of 10000. Plz make it correct, after that only we will be able to give your answer.

Comment: ive but (of total) in brackets so before voting down on a post please read the question properly.. 5,000 is 50%, you then pay another 2,500 towards the 10,000, which gives you 75%. the answer below was correct anyway so thanks for any help

Comment: Regardless of the answer, the question before the editing was not correctly formulated. Even if properly read.

Comment: thats a matter of opinion, Gordon got it no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want `max()`:

```
select FinanceID, CustomerID max(PercentageComplete) 
from Finances
group by FinanceID, CustomerID ;
```

Comment: bloody hell thats dead obvious, actually not used MAX since high school haha, cheers buddy

Comment: Hi @Crezzer7 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.